# Partially filling a rectangle with mxgraph

Tags: mxgraph, draw.io

Is it possible to fill only part of a shape (at least for a rectangle)? For instance 75% blue and 25% red as in a bargraph?

[image]

Or any advice on how to do it programmatically?

Of course I can always put a rectangle on top on another one but if I can do it with a single shape it would be better.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, draw.io doesn't support that but feel free to vote and track this feature request here:

https://trello.com/c/umCgQp6I/585-support-partial-filling

Regards,